# Traversing recursive data structure with access to ancestors

Tags: rust, tree-traversal, recursive-datastructures

I want to traverse a recursive data structure in Rust, where
the traversal function should have access to all ancestors already traversed.
What I currently have is something like this:

```rust
enum Tree<N> {
  Node(N, Vec<Box<Tree<N>>>),
}

// delete children of nodes that have an equivalent ancestor
fn traverse<N>(ancestors: &mut Vec<N>, t: Tree<N>) -> Tree<N>
where
  N: std::cmp::PartialEq + Clone
{
  let Tree::Node(n, ts) = t;
  if ancestors.contains(&n) {
    Tree::Node(n, Vec::new())
  }
  else {
    ancestors.push(n.clone()); // <------ TODO: ugly
    let ts = ts.into_iter().map(|bt| Box::new(traverse(ancestors, *bt))).collect();
    ancestors.pop(); // <------ TODO: ugly
    Tree::Node(n, ts)
  }
}
```

I am not happy with the way the ancestors are recorded in the `traverse` function:
Using a mutable `Vec` means that I have to remember to `pop()` after the `push()`.
Furthermore, I need to `clone()` every node.

What would be the idiomatic way to write the `traverse` function? Is it possible to write it without the cloning constraint?

**NB**:
In Haskell, I would use a `List` instead of a `Vec`, which would allow me to write this:

```hs
data Tree n =
  Node n [Tree n]

treeTraverse :: Eq a => [a] -> Tree a -> Tree a
treeTraverse ancestors (Node n ts) =
  if n `elem` ancestors
  then Node n []
  else Node n (map (treeTraverse (n:ancestors)) ts)
```